# primefaces tree node update issue with event Expand

Tags: primefaces, expand, treenode

In Primefaces, i want to create tree-node look like country>street>address. but i don't want get all info by first time. i'm using `NodeExpandEvent`, my code:

```
<p:tree id="treeId" value="#{bean.root}" var="item" selectionModel="single">
  <p:ajax event="expand" listener=#{bean.onNodeExpand} update="treeId"/>
  <p:treeNode> <h:outputText value=#{item.name}/>
</p:tre>
```

and in backing bean

```
//init values
public TreeNode createRoot(){
  TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode("root",null);
  Model model = new Model("---Select Option---",-1);// 2 properties name + value, and set label look like select one menu
  TreeNode child1 = new DefaultTreeNode(model,root);
  new DefaultTreeNode(new Model(),child1); //add new child to show expand
}

//handle event
public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) throws Exception{
  TreeNode currentNode = event.getTreeNode();
  Model first = (Model) cureentNode.getData(); //get model from TreeNode, name and value is ("", null)
  if(first.getName().equal("") && first.getValue() == null){
    currentNode.getChildren().clear(); //remove object earlier for expand
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++) {
       new DefaultTreeNode(new Model("Country"+i,i),currentNode);
    }
    currentNode.setExpanded(true); //importain, set expand for current node
  }
}
```

and in browser, i was update. i want show look like

```
<icon-expander> ----Select Option-----
    Country1
    Country2
    ...
    Country10
```

but, i only see

```
Country1
Country2
...
Contry10
```

what heppened??, if i using `selection-model` is `checkbox`, a set event is `NodeSelectEvent`, that's ok. but i wan't using event `expand`. please help me!

Comment: What is the issue? That you don't see the root node?

Comment: yes, i don't see that, and i can't select one of them for create next childrens node.